# Linq to objects error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: linq, linq-to-nhibernate

I am getting the following error when trying to return a list of new objects from a linq query. I am looking to return a stripped down entity for use in a selectbox and only need and id and name.

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

```
myViewModel.Regions = _regionRepository
                .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(x => new RegionForSelect {Id = x.Id.ToString(), Name = x.Name})
                .ToList();

 public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<RegionForSelect> Regions { get; set; }
}

public class RegionForSelect
{
    public string Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

Not sure where I am going wrong here.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: LINQ to Objects or LINQ to NHibernate? The title says one, the tag says another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any data in the collection? LINQ-to-NHibernate has a problem not resulting in an empty `List<T>` sometimes, but instead this error.  It can also be thrown when calling any parameter-less method against an empty field, or if the method has no parameters.

First, **try updating your nHibnerate LINQ version**, there have been lots of improvements.  If that fails, then try this (since you're working in memory anyway with Linq-to-Objects) to take the nHibernate provider out of the picture:

```
myViewModel.Regions = _regionRepository.All()
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x => new RegionForSelect {Id = x.Id.ToString(), Name = x.Name})
            .ToList();
```

If that still fails, replace `.All()` with `.ToList()`, this is not ideal in terms of performance or memory usage, but may be your only choice.  This kind of stuff that should *just work* is also why nHibernate and I went our separate ways some time ago :)

Comment: Chev, which NHibernate.Linq version ended up working for you? Thanks!